# Rails route params in angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm playing around with angular in my rails app.  This is not a single page app, i'm just using angular in a few places.  I'm having a hard time getting route params from the uri to use in my resources.

For instance, say I'm on the page /users/1/posts/2.  How do I get both user_id and id(for post)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking in Rails, or in Angular?

Comment: Hmm, well either I guess.  I need to be able to pass say, the user id to the resource to use my rails routes.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your angular app to pass the params to the controller your using for that page.

I would make a routes.js file doing something like:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/your-route', {
    controller: 'yourNGController',
    resolve: {
      params: ['$route', function($route){
        params = {user_id: $route.current.params.user_id}
        params.merge({post_id: $route.current.params.post_id})
        return params
      }]
    }
  })
}])
```

Then in your controller - "yourNGController' inject 'params' that you resolved in your route.  That should get your the info you need into the controller.

If using newer versions of angular you may also need to include the angular-route.js as $routeProvider was removed from the core angular components.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using ui-routes which makes this problem a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similair issue, and it is linked here: [Passing Rails ID to Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080197/passing-rails-id-to-angular)

I consider this solution a bit of a hack, so am interested in better approaches.